# Running out of cron.hourly won't import a Python module

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I have foo running out of cron.hourly.  It's been chmod +x'd, and it runs fine.  My problem is it does not recognize Python modules as importable.

I have ~/Foo/src, and within that lies the original Python code that I turned into an executable (main), as well as the other module I'm trying to import (foobar).  I have a **init**.py sitting there, empty, which should let either module be imported.  In fact, running my script with

```
python src/main.py
```

Everything works just fine and I don't get this error.  When running

```
run-parts -v /etc/cron.hourly/main
```

I get an error as follows:

```
ImportError: No module named foobar
run-parts: /etc/cron.hourly//main exited with return code 1
```

The way that I'm importing foobar is

```
os.chdir("/home/ubuntu/Foo/src/")
import foobar
```

Again, this works when running from Python, but not when running my executable.  Why is this, and what can I change to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/ubuntu/Foo/src")

import foobar
```

From the doc:

> sys.path
>
> A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules.
>   Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an
>   installation-dependent default.
>
> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list,
>   path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to
>   invoke the Python interpreter. If the script directory is not
>   available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the
>   script is read from standard input), path[0] is the empty string,
>   which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first.
>   Notice that the script directory is inserted before the entries
>   inserted as a result of PYTHONPATH.
>
> A program is free to modify this list for its own purposes.